# Share files and process between a few computers (windows)

Tags: windows, file-sharing, sharing

I have a few computers. One server for web projets and services, one for development, one my personal computer, one my tablet which I take when I need to move somewhere.

I'm a little bit tired to have a lot of remote desktops\team viewers opened in the same time.

It is painful even to copy files. Sometimes I need to build project in one computer and move it to another, and I need to do a lot of stuff for it.

I need open one remote desktop, build project, copy files to my current computer, open another remote desktop, copy files there, then run some scripts and do some actions. For sure I can use ftp and shared folders to automate the process but anyway it is not what I really want to have.

I desire to share everything between computers. i.e. I want to have one file system, when from one computer I can copy\paste files to another just in a two clicks. I want to have ability to run any command file from another computer without switching to remote desktop.

I'm using far manager in my everyday work. So I want to do all stuff from far manager or cmd.

Another litte thing. Access to server might have a lot of people and I don't want to share my personal files with them. So I would like to have some access ruules for this system.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

How about a network shared drive / directory? If all your devices are on the same network you can create a directory that is shared on the network. You can then edit it's permissions for certain users / groups. In the event you're not on the same network, you can try setting up a VPN (check with supervisors), and then you can access the drive / directory from anywhere through the VPN. In my home what I did was I bought a Raspberry Pi 2 and hosted a Samba Server on it to broadcast files I have on an external HDD connected to it, the reading is pretty decent, the writing is horrific, but it's file sharing none the less.

Comment: You should make clear that you do not need to share a whole drive: individual directories can be shared, so personal files can be excluded.

Comment: Ok...shared folders is an options, but a little bit complicated in setup (my computers in different networks). I would like to have something easy to use

Comment: Even if your computers are in different networks the VPN method still stands, thats why they were  created. BUT, if you can't do that, the least troublesome way to do this would be using (as mentioned by Kody Brown) something like dropbox, and install their client that way when you upload something, it'll sync to all devices (so to speak), and from there you can choose to copy the file for local use.

Answer (score 2):

What about Dropbox, OneDrive, or Google Drive? They are all nearly instant in replicating files and changes from each computer...

The files can be protected on each computer using EFS so no one, nor anything, can see those files except you.

To share your Desktop folder with the other computers via Dropbox:

All computers:

1. BACKUP your Desktop folder
2. Install Dropbox (free up to 2GB per account I think)

Computer #1:

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Click on your user name name on the left.
3. On the right side drag the Desktop folder into the Dropbox folder.

From the other computers:

1. Make sure Dropbox syncs the Desktop folder from computer #1.
2. Perform same steps for computer #1.
3. It will ask you to confirm location because a destination folder already exists.

Now, any changes on one computer get updated on all the others..

Comment: Can I share specific folders in cloud stores? For example, share desktop of one computer to another computer

Comment: In short, Yes. There are multiple ways to do it though. Each of the three I mentioned have a 'base' folder that you create your own folders under. You can also move your Desktop folder under the base folder if you want, then everything in your Desktop will be shared on all of the machines. (That is what I do..)